# how can i calculate the maximum number of concurrent uploads that an amazon ec2 server can handle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

i have an amazon ec2 instance that receives large file uploads.  after it receives them it then stores the file to an s3 bucket so this network traffic must be accounted for as well.

i'm trying to get a rough idea of how many concurrent uploads the server can handle before performance starts to suffer.

some assumptions have to be made, mainly the average upload speed of a user.  let's say 300kb/s.  what i'm looking for is a formula to get a rough idea how many concurrent users this instance can serve for large file uploads.

i realize that uploading directly to s3 buckets would totally eliminate this issue but it's not an option at this point.

Answer (score 1):

As with most things in EC2, the environment is multi-tenant. Larger instances get higher priority when it comes to network IO, but only the very largest instances get dedicated network ports. Even then, the bandwidth will be aggregated as it leaves the datacenter.

Your best option with this, like just about everything in EC2 is to test it.